# Get all PN Counters in a hazelcast cluster

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to use PN Counters on Hazelcast to maintain Inventory numbers for fast lookup , but at the same time i would also like to clear them all from time to time and reload them as a "true up".
Hazelcast allows PN Counter access by assigning a name but there is no way for a process to clear all the PN Counters in a cluster as there doesn't seem to be a client API to get a list of all PN Counters in the cluster.

How can i clear all PN counters in a cluster and start afresh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [getDistributedObjects](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#getDistributedObjects--) API, filter the PNCounters and destroy them.

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
client.getDistributedObjects()
        .stream()
        .filter(distributedObject -> distributedObject instanceof PNCounter)
        .forEach(DistributedObject::destroy);
```

As the documentation of the linked API suggests, the list of distributed objects are returned on a best-effort basis, but it should work just fine most of the time.